# Framework for scanning QR code from image ( not centered )

Tags: android, ios

Wondering if you know any mobile ([[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) or [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)) frameworks which allow you to find a `QR code` in an `image`, without it being in the center. Say i take a picture of a printed out piece of paper with text, `images` and a `QR code` somewhere in there.

Is there a framework, that could detect it?

Comment: Scanning Barcodes and QR Codes with AVFoundation on iOS7+ With the release of iOS 7, Apple included the ability to detect barcodes through its AVFoundation framework

Answer (score 0):

use ZBar SDK for BR and QR code scanning in our iPhone application.http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have used ZBar based framework in both iOS and Android Application and they work pretty well on both platform:

In  particular for Android I use this library:

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

And for iOS I suggest to use a static  library compiled for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64 architecture. Here an exaple:

https://markobl.com/2015/03/27/zbar-sdk-64-bit-for-iphone-6-and-ios-8-download/